# On react native WEB, open an app if it is installed, navigate to the store page if it isn't

Tags: expo, react-native-web

I am trying to redirect users that open my website from their phone to the app version.

The website is done with Expo and react native web, same code base as the app.

I tried to use `Linking.canOpenUrl("myapp://")`, but this always returns `true`, even if the app is not installed.

I tried to use `react-native-app-link` like the Expo team recommends but:

- The code is outdated, as it points to the old appstore urls
- Even by editing the code, `Linking.openURL("myapp://")` just fails without calling the `.catch()` call that would open the store link in case of failure.

My app is already configured to open urls to my website with the app.

FYI: I only tried this in debug mode, not production, as I don't want to move to production until I am 100% sure it will work.

Comment: Does `Linking.openURL("myapp://")` always fail? even if the app is installed?

Comment: @Mohammad No, if the app is installed, it actually opens it. The problem is that I can't tell from code if the app was opened or not and go to the store if it wasn't.

Comment: Is this iOS/Android/Both?

Comment: @Software2 Both